# Invalid template │ interpolation value; Cannot include the given value in a string template

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am using yaml template files to create a slo using a custom service. When i use templatefile to read the file it is throwing below error. Can someone suggest what could be the issue

Error :

```
Error: Error in function call
│ 
│   on slo1.tf line 25, in locals:
│   25:     for file                         in fileset(path.module, "slo/config/*.yaml") : yamldecode(templatefile(file, 
│   26:     {
│   27:         project_id                      = local.test_project,
│   28:         service_id                      = {for serv in resource.google_monitoring_custom_service.slo_services : serv["service_id"] => serv},
│   29:      }))
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.dataeng_project is "prj-test-02"
│     │ resource.google_monitoring_custom_service.slo_services is object with 2 attributes
│ 
│ Call to function "templatefile" failed:
│ slo/config/slo_uptime_latency500ms_window.yaml:2,12-22: Invalid template
│ interpolation value; Cannot include the given value in a string template:
│ string required..
╵
```

Main.tf

```
resource "google_monitoring_custom_service" "slo_services" {
  for_each                            = var.slo_service
  project                             = local.test_project  
  service_id                          = "svc-${var.domain}-${var.env}-${var.use_case}-${each.key}"
  display_name                        = "svc-${var.domain}-${var.env}-${var.use_case}-${each.key}"
}

locals                                  {
  slo_configs                         = [
    for file                         in fileset(path.module, "slo/config/*.yaml") : yamldecode(templatefile(file, 
    {
        project_id                      = local.test_project,
        service_id                      = {for serv in resource.google_monitoring_custom_service.slo_services : serv["service_id"] => serv},
  ]
}

module "slo_basic"                      {
  source                              = "terraform-google-modules/slo/google//modules/slo-native"
  for_each                            = {for config in local.slo_configs: config.slo_id => config}
  config                              = each.value
}
```

Variables.tf

```
variable "slo_service"       {
  type                 = set(string)
  default              = []
}
```

Slo_service =["composer","dataflow"]

Yaml file used :

```
project_id: ${project_id}
service: ${service_id}
slo_id: uptime-latency500ms-window
display_name: >
  90% of 600s windows are good, over a rolling 20-days period.
  Good window: Sum of uptime checks request latency < 500ms.
goal: 0.9
rolling_period_days: 20
type: windows_based_sli
method: metric_sum_in_range
window_period: 600s
metric_filter: >
  metric.type="monitoring.googleapis.com/uptime_check/request_latency"
  resource.type="uptime_url"
range_min: 0   # ms
range_max: 500 # ms
```

Comment: Since you are creating the resource using `for_each` (`resource.google_monitoring_custom_service.slo_services`), it will have key/value outlook, i.e., to reference any of the instances of the resource you need to provide the key. In other words, since the variable `slo_service` is a set, you cannot use the syntax you want. What is it exactly you want to achieve with the `service_id = {for serv in resource.google_monitoring_custom_service.slo_services : serv["service_id"] => serv},`? Shouldn't the `service_id` be a single value and not a map?

Comment: I want to fetch the value of service_id from the (resource.google_monitoring_custom_service.slo_services) block.

Comment: Ok, just so we're clear, you do understand that with the current way of doing it you will create a map of key/value pairs? You need a single value for the `service_id` if I understand how this works?

Comment: Yes I understand the current way is not right. If I am using a for loop I will create a map but I want only a value. How do you suggest I get the single value ? The service_id is passed on to the yaml file as highlighted which is the file for slo building .

Comment: What I see as an issue here is that there should probably be two `for`s, one for looping over files and the second one fetching the attribute values from the resources that were created.